# In java how to filter out a child node in xml depending on the string

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I'm writing a java program that is reading from a file path and creates a `sitemap.xml`.

The `sitemap.xml` will look like this

```
<loc>http://localhost/content/falcon/en/index/auto</loc>
<lastMod>2019-12-05</lastMod>
<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
<priority>0.0</priority>
<testing>admin</testing>
</url>
<url>

<loc>
http://localhost/content/falcon/en/index/auto/coverage
</loc>
<lastMod>2019-09-11</lastMod>
<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
<priority>0.9</priority>
<testing>admin</testing>
</url>

<url>
<loc>
http://localhost/content/falcon/en/index/auto/collectible
</loc>
<lastMod>2019-01-17</lastMod>
<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
<priority>0.9</priority>
<testing>ben.snedeker@tallwave.com</testing>
</url>

<url>
<loc>
http://localhost/content/falcon/en/index/auto/collectible/features-discounts
</loc>
<lastMod>2016-12-30</lastMod>
<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
<priority>0.8</priority>
<testing>usw8453</testing>
</url>
```

Inside the tags`<loc> </loc>`
Contains a urlthat is originally a string, depending on the url I want to be able to filter out the whole node including its siblings tags like `<lastMod> <changefrequency> <priority>` etc

This is the java that is writing to the xml sheet

```
         Resource resource = resourceResolver.getResource(sitemapRootPath);
        if(resource != null) {
            response.setContentType("text/xml;charset=UTF-8");  
            Page page = resource.adaptTo(Page.class);
            Iterator<Page> pageIterator = page.listChildren();

            //Initializing the XML document before writing data into the file
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder;
            try {
                LOG.info("Inside Try");
                builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document document = builder.newDocument();

                Element rootElement = document.createElement("urlset");
                rootElement.setAttribute("xmlns", "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9");
                document.appendChild(rootElement);

                for(int i = 0; i < staticPageData.length; i ++) {
                    createXMLNodeForStaticPages(document, rootElement, request, staticPageData[i]);
                }

                while(pageIterator.hasNext()) { 



                    createXMLNode(document, rootElement, request, pageIterator);
                }


                Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
                transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
                transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");

                //initialize StreamResult with File object to save to file
                StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
                DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
                transformer.transform(source, result);
                String xmlString = result.getWriter().toString();
                out.print(xmlString);
```

This is the method being called by the while loop up above. It writes the xml for the children pages as well in the bottom for loop.

```
public void createXMLNode(Document document, Element rootElement, SlingHttpServletRequest request, Iterator<Page> pageIterator) {
        Element headElement = document.createElement("url");
        Element locElement = document.createElement("loc");
        Element lastModElement = document.createElement("lastMod");
        Element changefreqElement = document.createElement("changefreq");
        Element priorityElement = document.createElement("priority");
        Element testingElement = document.createElement("testing");

        Node locElementNode = locElement;
        Node lastModElementNode = lastModElement;
        Node changefreqElementNode = changefreqElement;
        Node priorityElementNode = priorityElement;
        Node testingElementNode = testingElement;

        Page childPage = pageIterator.next();
        String location = request.getScheme() + "://" + request.getServerName() + childPage.getPath();
        locElementNode.setTextContent(location);


        LOG.error("childPage.getLastModified()" + childPage.getLastModified());
        if(null != childPage.getLastModified()) {
            Date date = childPage.getLastModified().getTime();
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
            try {
                dateFormat.parse("2019-07-15");
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            lastModElementNode.setTextContent(dateFormat.format(date));
        }


       String editor = childPage.getLastModifiedBy();

        changefreqElementNode.setTextContent("weekly");


        priorityElementNode.setTextContent(PriorityValue(location));
        testingElementNode.setTextContent(editor);


        rootElement.appendChild(headElement);
        headElement.appendChild(locElementNode);
        headElement.appendChild(lastModElementNode);
        headElement.appendChild(changefreqElementNode);
        headElement.appendChild(priorityElementNode);
        headElement.appendChild(testingElementNode);

        Iterator<Page> childPageIterator =  childPage.listChildren();




        while(childPageIterator.hasNext()) {

            createXMLNode(document, rootElement, request, childPageIterator);
        }
    }
```

I want to be able to skip a whole child node when a certain string is read. 
for example orignally the attribute inside a `loc` is just a string that is read from the file path where this java class is reading from.

```
        String location = request.getScheme() + "://" + request.getServerName() + childPage.getPath();
locElementNode.setTextContent(location);
```

it gets put in a variable location then we set `locElementNode` with that value. 
I want to be able to filter out the whole node when a reads a certain url string. The while loop should skip to the next element that is next .

Answer (score 0):

Well, all you need to do is just add logic to check returned string before creating any elements and appending them

```java
public void createXMLNode(Document document, Element rootElement, SlingHttpServletRequest request, Iterator<Page> pageIterator) {

        String location = request.getScheme() + "://" + request.getServerName() + childPage.getPath();
        if (location.equals("<banned url>") {
            return;
        }
        Element headElement = document.createElement("url");
        Element locElement = document.createElement("loc");
        Element lastModElement = document.createElement("lastMod");
        Element changefreqElement = document.createElement("changefreq");
        Element priorityElement = document.createElement("priority");
        Element testingElement = document.createElement("testing");

        Node locElementNode = locElement;
        Node lastModElementNode = lastModElement;
        Node changefreqElementNode = changefreqElement;
        Node priorityElementNode = priorityElement;
        Node testingElementNode = testingElement;

        Page childPage = pageIterator.next();        
        locElementNode.setTextContent(location);

 ....
```